# Can the Android SDK be Stored in a different location

Tags: android, sdk

A this point in time my SDK and affiliated tools are stored on my C ( C:\User\Jeff\App\AppData\Local\Android\sdk) drive is there a way of moving everything to another drive without android studio or other programs blowing up with errors?

p.s. im new to this sorry

Comment: What "other programs" are you thinking of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move the SDK, the next time you open Android Studio, it should ask for the location again. You can also manually retarget it via `File > Project Structure > SDK Location`.